# OOP compatibility error on basic PHP pricinple

Tags: php, inheritance, php-7

I have two classes as follows:

```
<?php

abstract class A {

    public function update(array $one, array $two) {
        echo $one;
        echo $two;
    }
}
?>
```

Then B inherits the Class A:

```
<?php
include ("A.php");
class B extends A {
public function update(array $one) {
    $two = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bar" => "foo",
    );
    parent::update($one, $two);
}
}
?>
```

When I try to compile B, I get the following error:

> Declaration of B::update(array $one) should be compatible with A::update(array $one, array $two) in B.php on line 3

It is obvious, that there is a problem with the B::update. I am giving to the A::update two arrays. But somehow I am missing something. 
I have tried to initialize in a constructor. And I have also tried to add the second array manually to the A::update (parent::update), but I seem to get the same error.
Has anybody an idea, why I am getting this problem? My php version: v7.0.18 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You define `A()` as needing two parameters in your abstract class and then try to define it having two parameters in your class that inherits from it. You can't do that.

Comment: But since the signature is not the same, is it not clear that I am not trying to override it per se? What is bothersome is the fact, that this exact code has worked before. But since I jumped to the php version I have now, I get this error.

Comment: The error was always there, you have just suppressed it in your previous PHP configuration. And PHP only identifies functions by their name; there's no two ways about it that you *are* overriding the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because PHP does method **overriding** not method **overloading**. So method signatures must match exactly.

To override the function in the base class, a method must have the identical "Signature" to the one it is displacing.

A signature consists of the name, the parameters (and parameter order), and the return type.

This is the essence of polymorphism, and is where object-oriented programming gains much of its power. If you don't need to override the parent's methods, give your new method a different name.

Comment: I am a newbie in php. And for that reason, I had no idea, that overloading was not possible on php. I just changed the name and now I am having no errors anymore.

Comment: Anyways you can achieve overloading with __call() or else with the help of func_get_args(). But __call() is not recommended, most of the modern languages are not allowing for overloading. Hope that helps. Please refer this link for more info : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 1):

The issue that PHP is trying to point out is this:

```
function caller(A $a) {
    $a->update($foo, $bar);
}

caller(new B);
```

Since `B extends A`, `B` is an `instanceof A`. Any code that type hints against `A` will also accept a `B`, **and expects the interface to be identical.** That's why interfaces should be compatible.